# codesign (MAC 10.10) and customization support

Tags: xcode, macos, code-signing, codesign, osx-yosemite

Pre-Yosemite could exclude certain files from codesign earlier by [specifying resource rules](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/xcode/301731-resourcerules-plist-how-do-exclude-specific-files-from-codesigning.html) but starting with Yosemite release (OS X 10.10) [--resource-rules are oboleted](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG205).
Is there still a way to exclude certain files so that signature verification ignores them?
I don't want gatekeeper to be throwing warnings:

```
$spctl -a -t execute my.app
```

The requirement here is that after codesigning app can be language customized by administrators and this customization gets updated in the resource language folders (.lproj).

Comment: TN2206 seems to suggest that it can't be done.  Consider putting the extra localization data outside the app, perhaps in `/Library/Application Support/nameofmyapp` or `~/Library/Application Support/nameofmyapp`.

Comment: Thats what I am implementing right now, but it means changes in the code itself. BTW, this doc explicitly mentions it -> **Code signatures made in Mavericks and later always seal all files in a bundle;**

Comment: Elsewhere in the same doc it says "It records substantially all files by default. There are no default "holes"."  I'm curious about "substantially all" versus "all".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created symlinks of InfoPlist.strings file during build time and then during installation created actual files on the system as desired.

Build time

```
my.app/Content/Resources/
my.app/Content/Resources/es.lproj/InfoPlist.strings <-- soft link to /Library/Application\ Support/com.myapp/es.lproj/InfoPlist.strings 
my.app/Content/Resources/ru.lproj/InfoPlist.strings
```

Installation time:

```
 app.zip (contains myapp.pkg + config file) <--- postscript file creates /Library/Application\ Support/com.myapp/*.lproj/InfoPlist.strings based on config file
```

Although symlinks are recorded in v2 signatures, but above procedure doesn't break codesign signature validation.

This changes application's name in main menu, but finder still reads from Info.plist file.